# Drawing a circle around text within itemize and enumerate on a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, enumerate, itemize, circles

I have the following code that defines a single frame of a `beamer` presentation:

```
\begin{frame}{Focus on Merkel Cells}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{1875}: Merkel cells discovered by Friedrich Merkel
  \item \textbf{1969}: Merkel cell-neurite complexes implicated in
    touch reception
  \item \textbf{1969-2014}: Unresolved debate
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item A$\beta$ SAI neurons are mechanoreceptive (analagous to
        olfaction and all other LTMRs)
      \item Merkel cells are mechanoreceptive (analagous to taste and
        hearing)
      \item \alert{\textbf{Both are mechanoreceptive: A$\beta$ SAI rapid, Merkel
            sustained}}
      \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{2014}: Explosion of new evidence
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I want to draw an empty black circle around the text `A$\beta$ SAI rapid,` and I don't care whether other text gets covered up.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an option using TikZ and its `tikzmark` and `fit` libraries

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Focus on Merkel Cells}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{1875}: Merkel cells discovered by Friedrich Merkel
  \item \textbf{1969}: Merkel cell-neurite complexes implicated in
    touch reception
  \item \textbf{1969-2014}: Unresolved debate
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item A$\beta$ SAI neurons are mechanoreceptive (analagous to
        olfaction and all other LTMRs)
      \item Merkel cells are mechanoreceptive (analagous to taste and
        hearing)
      \item \alert{\textbf{Both are mechanoreceptive: \tikzmark{start}A$\beta$ SAI rapid\tikzmark{end}, Merkel
            sustained}}
      \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{2014}: Explosion of new evidence
  \end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node<2>[draw,line width=2pt,cyan,circle,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result (compile two or three times to the circle to reach its final position):

Since TikZ and `beamer` cooperate, you can use overlays as in, for example,

```
\node<2>[draw,line width=2pt,cyan,circle,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
```

so the circle will appear on the second slide.

[image]

Using an ellipse (requires the `shapes.geometric` library):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Focus on Merkel Cells}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{1875}: Merkel cells discovered by Friedrich Merkel
  \item \textbf{1969}: Merkel cell-neurite complexes implicated in
    touch reception
  \item \textbf{1969-2014}: Unresolved debate
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item A$\beta$ SAI neurons are mechanoreceptive (analagous to
        olfaction and all other LTMRs)
      \item Merkel cells are mechanoreceptive (analagous to taste and
        hearing)
      \item \alert{\textbf{Both are mechanoreceptive: A\tikzmark{start}$\beta$ SAI rapi\tikzmark{end}d, Merkel
            sustained}}
      \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{2014}: Explosion of new evidence
  \end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[draw,line width=2pt,cyan,ellipse,inner ysep=15pt,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect, thanks!  is there an easy way to flatten the circle a little, make it more of an oval?  i tried to replace `circle` with `oval`, but that didn't work.  a rectangle would work, too.  i replaced `circle` with `rectangle`, and that was recognized, but the rectangle is too short.  i'm not sure how to increase the height.

Comment: @dbliss Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @dbliss With a rectangle, add something like `minimum height=1cm` to the `\node` options.

Comment: this seemed to be working for me, but when i did a final check of my PDF (i'm printing to PDF), the circle/ellipsis/rectangle was offset (to the right and up, a good deal) from the words of interest.  i'm not sure how or why this would've happened, and i didn't see an obvious way to fix it.  any ideas?

Comment: @dbliss No without seeing the actual code. Did you run the code two or three rimes?