# Drawing overlay graphics over minted code

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minted

I want to draw ellipses around some code I have on a slide, as overlays, per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268624/7302). However, it doesn't seem to work. Indeed, XeLaTeX isn't even rendering the second slide.

My code is something like:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]{Frame title}
  \begin{minted}[autogobble,fontfamily=myfont,escapeinside=||}{c}
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      return |\tikzmark{start}|0|\tikzmark{end}|;
    }
  \end{minted}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node<2>[draw,line width=2,cyan,circle,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

I'm using latexmk, FWIW. I tested the code linked in the aforementioned answer and I get the correct output, so I guess it's doing the correct number of passes. However, when I remove the minted environment, it still doesn't work:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]{Frame title}
  Hello \tikzmark{start}World\tikzmark{end}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node<2>[draw,line width=2,cyan,circle,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? Does putting `\pause` before your tikzpicture help?

Comment: The `\pause` made no difference. I found the problem, though, and added my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem. If I remove the `fragile=singleslide` frame option, then it works in the second example. However, the minted environment needs at least the `fragile` option. This combination, fortunately, works:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Frame title}
  \begin{minted}[autogobble,fontfamily=myfont,escapeinside=||}{c}
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      return |\tikzmark{start}|0|\tikzmark{end}|;
    }
  \end{minted}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node<2>[draw,line width=2,cyan,circle,fit={(pic cs:start) (pic cs:end)}] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```